# Window leaking air, job for a carpenter or a plasterer? (Or me?)

Tags: insulation, windows

In my bathroom, the window is leaking air: putting my hand at the connection between the window and the ceiling I can feel a breeze of cold air passing through.

The window itself is quite old (30 years), but the plaster / drywall around it seems to be equally damaged.

This is costing me a fortune, since I'd like to keep my bathroom relatively hot, but I don't know if fixing this is a job for a carpenter, a plasterer or me (or in other words, should I change the window, have the drywall fixed, maybe both, or is there something a very - very bad with his hands guy can do?).

[image: Overview of the window]
[image: Close-up]

Edit: The window does open, and there is some kind of metallic gasket:

[image: Close-up]

Comment: That picture seems to be of a window/skylight in the ceiling.  If so would think a roofer might be the best, since if air is leaking in, then rain/water can leak in also, and it would be best to seal from the outside.

Comment: Does that window open?   Even if it doesn't, it might be as simple as replacing the gasket/weather stripping.   BTW:  Don't fall off your roof.

Comment: @SteveWellens It does open, and there is indeed some kind of gasket (I've edited a picture in), but replacing this seems like way out of skill range (my skill ceiling is mounting a shelf on a wall)

Answer (score 1):

The skylight looks like it can be opened ( wood frame on window and a wood frame on opening). In which case; 1- make sure it is closed tightly, and 2- replace old weather stripping.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. There is no stripping, but some kind of metallic gasket. I've looked at replacing this, but it looks way too complicated to handle on my own. https://www.roofingoutlet.co.uk/products/velux-ew-6000-replacement-tile-flashing-with-insulation-for-upgrading-old-windows?variant=38620896001